# Ubuntu 18.04 animations laggy

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 for a long time, but i'm trying to switch to GNOME for a time now. But everytime that i install ubuntu 18.04, i get really choppy animations, with a lag, tearing. on Xorg the peformance is better, but no real solution.

My laptop is a:

- Intel I5 7200U (HD Intel® 620)
- 8GB RAM
- NVIDIA 940mx (i have not installed the drivers, because the computer get really hot when using it.)

Comment: So you are saying that the nvidia driver is slower than Nouveau?

Comment: Alternatively, you can disable animation altogether. Install GNOME tweaks, and disable Desktop Animation under Appearance.